# Eclipse plugins errors?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, editor

I am new to eclipse, I just installed eclipse Indigo.
Whenever I want to installed new plugins,I receive this error:

> Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
>   No repository found at //archive.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/updates/N/.
>   No repository found at //dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/dsdp/org.eclipse.tm.tcf/releases/0.4.0.
>   No repository found at //download.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.5.0/.
>   No repository found at //download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/updates/N/.
>   No repository found at //archive.eclipse.org/tools/ve/downloads/drops/1.5.0/.
>   No repository found at //download.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.4/.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Marketplace provides site URL, which as of now is:
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.0/1.0.100.20110804-1717

Earlier the URL was provided by Sonatype.
http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e/

I tried adding both these in Eclipse --> Help --> Software Update. Both of these haven't worked for me.

However if you open the Sontaype URL in a web browser, it will open and will show various versions of plugins. One of the old version is

"http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e/0.10.0.20100209-0800/".

Add one of the versions to sites and refresh.  Eclipe will attempt to install the plugin. For me, however the installation failed due to some dependancies.

Answer (score 1):

Your are probably using an old version of eclipse that contains URLs for update sites that don't exist anymore. Either remove those update sites (go to Windows -> preferences -> Install/update -> available software sites), or just install recent version of eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently.  If you are behind a proxy you may need to double check your network connection configuration.  Open up the preferences window and go to:

General > Network Connections

Check that you proxy entries are correctly configured with whatever authentication info you need.

Answer (score 1):

Open Help>install new software, there click on the link "Available software site" there you would find lots of paths checked that are actually causing errors, these paths would be same which you just saw in "Details" of your error log which you got after checking for software updates. Now just uncheck the paths that are causing errors.
It worked for me.